# Query data from Parse.com, iterate through, add certain parts to an NSObject, and add the object to an array of objects

Tags: for-loop, ios7, nsarray, parse-platform, nsobject

I'm using iOS7 Xcode 5 with Parse.com's SDK. While querying data via parse, I'm trying to construct a Person (NSObject) for each returned object and create an NSArray of defaultPeople.
Here is the code for the Person:

Person.h

```
// Person.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger age;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *gender;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *location;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tagline;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *objectId;

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name
                       image:(UIImage *)image
                         age:(NSUInteger)age
                      gender:(NSString*)gender
                    location:(NSString*)location
                     tagline:(NSString*)tagline
                    objectId:(NSString*)objectId;

@end
```

Person.m:

```
// Person.m

#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

#pragma mark - Object Lifecycle

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name
                       image:(UIImage *)image
                         age:(NSUInteger)age
                      gender:(NSString*)gender
                    location:(NSString *)location
                     tagline:(NSString*)tagline
                    objectId:(NSString *)objectId {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _name = name;
        _image = image;
        _age = age;
        _gender = gender;
        _location = location;
        _tagline = tagline;
        _objectId = objectId;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Now here's the code I am using to try and create the array in my view controller .m file :

```
- (NSArray *)defaultPeople {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSLog(@"Current City for Querying: %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"CurrentCity"]);
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"CurrentCity"]) {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
        [query whereKey:@"CurrentCity" equalTo:[defaults objectForKey:@"CurrentCity"]];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    // The find succeeded.
                    NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
                    // Do something with the found objects
                    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                        NSString *userID = object.objectId;
                        NSString *first = [object objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
                        NSString *city = [object objectForKey:@"CurrentCity"];
                        NSUInteger age = (int)[object objectForKey:@"Age"];
                        NSString *gender = [object objectForKey:@"Gender"];
                        NSString *tagline = [object objectForKey:@"Tagline"];

                        Person *p = [[Person alloc] 
                                            initWithName:first
                                                   image:[UIImage imageWithData:
                                                         [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:                                                                                            
                                                         [NSURL URLWithString:
                                                         [object objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]]]]
                                                 age:age
                                              gender:gender
                                            location:city
                                             tagline:tagline
                                            objectId:userID];
                [self.people addObject:p]
                }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];
    }
    return self.people; //people was defined in the interface as: 
                        //@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *people;
}
```

I know that the querying is fine because I've NSLogged each NSString/NSUInteger in the for loop and it always returns the right value. My problem is creating a new Person object from those values and adding it to the defaultPeople array after each iteration. The result of this code is that my defaultPeople array always returns (null). PLEASE HELP!!! Thanks :)

Clayton

Comment: Where in your code are you adding the new Person object to an array?

Comment: @Jacob - edited it to where I had it, take a look. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys FINALLY I figured out how do do this in a block that actually works:

```
- (void)queryForAllPostsNearLocation:(CLLocation *)currentLocation withNearbyDistance:(CLLocationAccuracy)nearbyDistance {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:1 forKey:@"Users"];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if (query.countObjects == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    // Create a PFGeoPoint using the current location (to use in our query)
    PFGeoPoint *userLocation =
    [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:[Global shared].LastLocation.latitude longitude:[Global shared].LastLocation.longitude];

    // Create a PFQuery asking for all wall posts 1km of the user
    [query whereKey:@"CurrentCityCoordinates" nearGeoPoint:userLocation withinKilometers:10];
    // Include the associated PFUser objects in the returned data
    [query includeKey:@"objectId"];
    //Run the query in background with completion block
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) { // The query failed
        NSLog(@"Error in geo query!");
    } else { // The query is successful
        defaultPeople = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        // 1. Find new posts (those that we did not already have)
        // In this array we'll store the posts returned by the query
        NSMutableArray *people = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
        // Loop through all returned PFObjects
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            // Create an object of type Person with the PFObject
            Person *p = [[Person alloc] init];
            NSString *userID = object.objectId;
            p.objectId = userID;

            NSString *first = [object objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
            p.name = first;

            NSString *city = [object objectForKey:@"CurrentCity"];
            p.location = city;

            NSString *age = [object objectForKey:@"Age"];
            p.age = age;

            NSString *gender = [object objectForKey:@"Gender"];
            p.gender = gender;

            NSString *tagline = [object objectForKey:@"Tagline"];
            p.tagline = tagline;

            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[object objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]]]]];
            p.image = img;
            if (![p.objectId isEqualToString:myID] && ![p.gender isEqualToString:myGender] && ![people containsObject:p]) {
                [people addObject:p];
                NSLog(@"Person: %@",p);
            }
        }
        [defaultPeople addObjectsFromArray:people];
        [[Global shared] setDefaultPeople:defaultPeople];
        NSLog(@"Default People: %@",[Global shared].defaultPeople);
        NSLog(@"Success. Retrieved %lu objects.", (unsigned long)[Global shared].defaultPeople.count);
        if (defaultPeople.count == 0) {
            [defaults setBool:0 forKey:@"Users"];
        } else {
            [defaults setBool:1 forKey:@"Users"];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

The BOOL returns on the bottom are to let the controller know whether or not to switch view controllers when prompted. If the switch controller toggle is hit, it only switches if the BOOL = 1, i.e. there are people in the area.

Thanks for all your help guys. Seriously.

Comment: Thanks to you especially [@Jacob](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2584268/jacob) for sticking this out with me!

Comment: Would you at least up vote my answer if I helped you? Thanks, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return people inside the block, otherwise it will hit the return statement before it finishes finding the objects. It's finding them asynchronously with the block.

Another alternative is to get rid of the block and do:

```
NSArray *array = [query findObjects];

for (PFObject *object in array) {
                        NSString *userID = object.objectId;
                        NSString *first = [object objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
                        NSString *city = [object objectForKey:@"CurrentCity"];
                        NSUInteger age = (int)[object objectForKey:@"Age"];
                        NSString *gender = [object objectForKey:@"Gender"];
                        NSString *tagline = [object objectForKey:@"Tagline"];

                        Person *p = [[Person alloc] 
                                            initWithName:first
                                                   image:[UIImage imageWithData:
                                                         [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:                                                                                            
                                                         [NSURL URLWithString:
                                                         [object objectForKey:@"PictureURL"]]]]
                                                 age:age
                                              gender:gender
                                            location:city
                                             tagline:tagline
                                            objectId:userID];
                [self.people addObject:p];

}

return self.people;
```

Comment: I get what you're saying. I have to do it in a block (asynchronously) because of all the data. I tried putting return self.people inside the block but not am getting an error about "incompatible pointer types" between the block and return array

Comment: @rockandride maybe put the code to fine the objects in another method and then in your main method above return a call to the method where the objects are being found.

Comment: tried that already too - no dice. I even did it on the root view and stored it in a singleton hoping that by the time that this controller popped up that the data would load etc. - still nothing.

Comment: @rockandride do all of the objects not load if you don't use a block?

Comment: @rockandride that doesn't sound right. Can you explain more?

Comment: honestly I don't know but it workx. I can't upvote your answer either sorry. I initially tried but it said I don't have enough reputaion

Answer (score 0):

[self.people addObject:p] is happening in the background thread so "return self.people" happens before self.people is updated. Thats why it is always returns nil.

instead of [query findObjectsInBackground] you can do
NSArray *objects = [query findObjects]